# Loading Compiled Matlab Shared Library in Python Using Ctypes

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, ctypes, mcc

I am trying to do Incomplete Cholesky Decomposition in Python, but no direct Python package I can find.

Since the most available codes I can find online are written in Matlab, I want to take a detour by

- compiling the matlab code to a shared library (I am using Mac OS and MATLAB_R2014a, so it should produce `.dylib` file)
- load library in Python by using Ctypes

The following lists the detailed steps:

## 0. Download Matlab Source Code

The code can be downloaded from F. Bach's webpage [link to zip file](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/csi/csi-1.0.zip), which contains the following files:

```
panc:csi-1.0 panc25$ ls
center.m            csi.dll             csi.mexglx          csi_gaussian.dll    csi_gaussian.mexglx readme.txt
csi.c               csi.m               csi_gaussian.c      csi_gaussian.m      demo_csi.m          sqdist.m
```

## 1. Compiling the matlab code to a shared library

Then by following [this post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/02/03/creating-c-shared-libraries-and-dlls/), I run the command:

```
mcc -v -W cpplib:libcsi -T link:lib csi
```

After around a minute, the terminal prints `MEX completed successfully` and in my folder there are

```
panc:csi-1.0 panc25$ ls
center.m             csi.m                csi_gaussian.dll     demo_csi.m           libcsi.exports       readme.txt
csi.c                csi.mexglx           csi_gaussian.m       libcsi.cpp           libcsi.h             sqdist.m
csi.dll              csi_gaussian.c       csi_gaussian.mexglx  libcsi.dylib         mccExcludedFiles.log
```

where `libcsi.dylib` is the shared library I want.

## 2. Loading library in Python

Then I open `IPython` and try to load the library:

```
In [1]: import ctypes

In [2]: ctypes.C
ctypes.CDLL       ctypes.CFUNCTYPE

In [2]: ctypes.CDLL('libcsi.dylib')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b6d0c1a91651> in <module>()
----> 1 ctypes.CDLL('libcsi.dylib')

/Users/panc25/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    363
    364         if handle is None:
--> 365             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    366         else:
    367             self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(libcsi.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmwmclmcrrt.8.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/panc25/Downloads/csi-1.0/libcsi.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

This problem persists even after I replace file name in `ctypes.CDLL('libcsi.dylib')` with the full path.

**So I am confused. The shared library is there, but why Python says "image not found"?**

## BTW

SInce the source code also provide C implementation through `mex.h`, I also tried to first create a `.mex` file, then compile the `.mex` to a shared library as follows:

```
panc:csi-1.0 panc25$ mex csi.c
```

which created the `csi.mexmaci64` file. Then according to [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98867-how-do-i-create-a-c-shared-library-from-mex-files-using-the-matlab-compiler), I called:

```
panc:csi-1.0 panc25$ mcc -B csharedlib:csi2 csi.mexmaci64
```

which produced `csi2.dylib` file.

But when I tried to load it in Python, I had the same error.

**Could anyone let me know what is wrong?**

Comment: The compiled library depends on libmwmclmcrrt.8.3.dylib. Add the directory where it's located to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid Matlab altogether, and instead use the Incomplete Cholesky Decomposition available in PyMC2:

```
from pymc.gp.incomplete_chol import ichol_full
```

The f2py wrapped Fortran code, that was actually adapted from a MEX file, can be found [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/master/pymc/gp/incomplete_chol.f#L448). So you could use this independently of PyMC2 if need be.

If you are interested, you could also propose to add this function to scipy (see this [githib issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2508) ).

Comment: Since I am using ICD to decompose a Gram matrix (for a given kernel funciton) which is just a covariance function, I figured using `pymc.gp.Covariance` class would be better. It implemented a `cholesky` method to apply ICD without evaluate the complete matrix. However, I found an issue, see [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/40). Basically, I found by using `Covariance.cholesky` doesn't reduce the rank. Any idea on what's going on?